# Why am I denied access to phpmyadmin?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, phpmyadmin

Here is what my `phpmyadmin.conf` file looks like:

```
#
#  Web application to manage MySQL
#

<Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from 192.168.0.2
  Allow from 192.168.0.219
</Directory>

Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
Alias /mysqladmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

I did restart the apache service after making changes as well.  I used the following commands to try to restart apache:

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd.service

sudo apachectl restart
```

The server I'm working with is running CentOS and is hosted on the same LAN and my local ip is listed under the allows. Navigating to `http://serverip/phpmyadmin` results in a:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.
```

Message.  Any ideas?  I followed guides that told me to do it this way, but it just doesn't seem to want to work.

**Edit**:  This message shows up in my httpd `error_log`:

```
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

But I can't find a configuration file in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`.

Comment: What are the permissions on the `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` directory?

Comment: @datUser, 0755/drwxr-xr-x

Comment: @datUser, I added some additional information to the question if that helps.  It's just really odd because from what I have read, these permissions should work.  I also ran `chown -R nobody:nobody phpmyadmin` from the `/usr/share/` folder and that didn't help.

Comment: That is just the GET request, `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`. I would try changing the `phpmyadmin.conf` file to `Order Allow,Deny` and comment out the whitelist and add `Allow from All`. Restart apache and see if you can get in.

Comment: @datUser, Changed the order to `Allow,Deny` and added `#` characters to the allows to comment them out.  I then restarted using `systemctl restart httpd.service`.  Still no luck getting in unfortunately.

Comment: Try adding the following to the config file under that directory: `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews` right above the `Allow` statement.

Comment: @datUser, Still no luck unfortunately.  are there any error logs I can check to maybe get more information as to what is going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

**Warning: The below (`Require all granted`) allows access from ANY ip.**

I had to add this to my `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file:

```
<Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then restart the apache service:

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd.service
```

I have also read that selinux can cause this, so you can check to see if that is causing issues by putting selinux into permissive mode:

```
sudo setenforce 0
getenforce
```

take selinux out of permissive mode:

```
sudo setenforce 1
getenforce
```

It's also a good idea to check permissions on the `/usr/share/phpmyadmin` directory to make sure they are set to something like 0755.

Comment: The "Require all granted" is the new apache 2.4 syntax

Answer (score 0):

Right before the error message in the log it will have the client ip address.

```
[client 10.0.2.2:52570] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
```

which you can then use in the rule in the conf file (this is the location for Centos 7).

```
sudo vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf
```

and edit so that it looks similar to the below. The last part of the IP is replaced with a zero, and a mask "/15" to allow anyone on the subnet 10.0.2.x access.

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
       Require ip 10.0.2.0/15
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
     Allow from 10.0.2.0/15
   </IfModule>
</Directory>
```